# How to animate zooming into an image without changing the image size

Tags: objective-c

How can I recreate a slight zoom in to an image using animations?

I have a uiimageview and I want it to look like we zoom in to the image after 1 second, lasting 1 second, but the uiimageview size must not change.

Something like this but the image view changes its size:

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1
                                   delay:0
                                 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                              animations:^{
                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0
                                                          relativeDuration:1
                                                                animations:^{
                                                                    self.imageView.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
                                                                }];
                              }
                              completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                              }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add UIImageView as a child view of UIScrollView and set its zooming options. Here, look at this [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html).